# I get following error while initializing gdb debugger in Cypress FX3

Tags: c, gdb

While i was going through the Superspeed Explorer Kit User guide
http://www.cypress.com/file/133836/download (page no.36) the debugging of an example program 'USBBulkSourceSinkLED' i get error.

98^error,msg="\"monitor\" command not supported by this target."
error,msg="You can't do that when your target is `exec'"

```
95 target remote localhost:3333
&"target remote localhost:3333\n"
target remote localhost:3333
&"localhost:3333: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.\n"
localhost:3333: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
95^error,msg="localhost:3333: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."
(gdb) 
96 monitor reset halt
&"monitor reset halt\n"
&"\"monitor\" command not supported by this target.\n"
monitor reset halt
"monitor" command not supported by this target.
96^error,msg="\"monitor\" command not supported by this target."
(gdb) 
97 monitor mww 0xFFFFF014 0xFFFFFFFF
monitor mww 0xFFFFF014 0xFFFFFFFF
"monitor" command not supported by this target.
&"monitor mww 0xFFFFF014 0xFFFFFFFF\n"
&"\"monitor\" command not supported by this target.\n"
97^error,msg="\"monitor\" command not supported by this target."
(gdb) 
98 monitor mww 0x40000000 0xE3A00015
&"monitor mww 0x40000000 0xE3A00015\n"
&"\"monitor\" command not supported by this target.\n"
monitor mww 0x40000000 0xE3A00015
"monitor" command not supported by this target.
98^error,msg="\"monitor\" command not supported by this target."
(gdb) 
99 monitor mww 0x40000004 0xEE090F31
&"monitor mww 0x40000004 0xEE090F31\n"
monitor mww 0x40000004 0xEE090F31
&"\"monitor\" command not supported by this target.\n"
"monitor" command not supported by this target.
99^error,msg="\"monitor\" command not supported by this target."
(gdb) 
100 monitor mww 0x40000008 0xE240024F
&"monitor mww 0x40000008 0xE240024F\n"
&"\"monitor\" command not supported by this target.\n"
100^error,msg="\"monitor\" command not supported by this target."
(gdb) 
monitor mww 0x40000008 0xE240024F
"monitor" command not supported by this target.
101 monitor mww 0x4000000C 0xEE090F11
&"monitor mww 0x4000000C 0xEE090F11\n"
&"\"monitor\" command not supported by this target.\n"
101^error,msg="\"monitor\" command not supported by this target."
(gdb) 
monitor mww 0x4000000C 0xEE090F11
"monitor" command not supported by this target.
102 monitor reg pc 0x40000000
&"monitor reg pc 0x40000000\n"
monitor reg pc 0x40000000
&"\"monitor\" command not supported by this target.\n"
"monitor" command not supported by this target.
102^error,msg="\"monitor\" command not supported by this target."
(gdb) 
103 si
&"si\n"
&"The program is not being run.\n"
si
The program is not being run.
103^error,msg="The program is not being run."
(gdb) 
104 si
&"si\n"
si
&"The program is not being run.\n"
The program is not being run.
104^error,msg="The program is not being run."
(gdb) 
105 si
&"si\n"
&"The program is not being run.\n"
si
The program is not being run.
105^error,msg="The program is not being run."
(gdb) 
106 si
&"si\n"
&"The program is not being run.\n"
si
The program is not being run.
106^error,msg="The program is not being run."
(gdb) 
107-environment-directory "C:/Users/Jasmin Maria Jose/Desktop/FST/Workspace/USBBulkSourceSinkLED" "C:/Users/Jasmin Maria Jose/Desktop/FST/Workspace/USBBulkSourceSinkLED/Debug"
107^done,source-path="C:/Users/Jasmin Maria Jose/Desktop/FST/Workspace/USBBulkSourceSinkLED;C:/Users/Jasmin Maria Jose/Desktop/FST/Workspace/USBBulkSourceSinkLED/Debug;$cdir;$cwd"
(gdb) 
108 info threads
&"info threads\n"
~"No threads.\n"
108^done
(gdb) 
109-data-list-register-names
109^done,register-names=["r0","r1","r2","r3","r4","r5","r6","r7","r8","r9","r10","r11","r12","sp","lr","pc","f0","f1","f2","f3","f4","f5","f6","f7","fps","cpsr","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]
(gdb) 
110-break-insert -t main
110^done,bkpt={number="1",type="breakpoint",disp="del",enabled="y",addr="0x40004a00",func="main",file="../cyfxbulksrcsink.c",fullname="c:\\users\\jasmin maria jose\\desktop\\fst\\workspace\\usbbulksourcesinkled\\cyfxbulksrcsink.c",line="1143",thread-groups=["i1"],times="0",original-location="main"}
(gdb) 
111-stack-info-depth
111^error,msg="No registers."
(gdb) 
112-stack-info-depth
112^error,msg="No registers."
(gdb) 
113-stack-list-frames
113^error,msg="No registers."
(gdb) 
114-stack-list-frames 0 1
114^error,msg="No registers."
(gdb) 
115 load
&"load\n"
load
&"You can't do that when your target is `exec'\n"
You can't do that when your target is `exec'
115^error,msg="You can't do that when your target is `exec'"
(gdb)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check this: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the `target remote` command failed:

```
&"localhost:3333: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.\n"
```

The `monitor` command only works with remotes, it has no meaning with a local target.  And, when `target remote` has failed, you're still using the `exec` target.

Comment: Normally it means either the gdbserver on the target isn't running, or that you gave the wrong address.

Comment: Thank-you Tom. Yea! I resolved it.. I had few errors&warnings in my code. on resolving it I could debug it!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was trying to debug a code which had few header file errors(not including appropriate headers). After resolving all errors and warnings the debugging went well.